# How to disable smarty cache for javascript

Tags: caching, smarty

I have an issue with smarty cache. In my tpl files i have some javascript codes, for eg. a dropdown options, and onchange this options the browser navigate to a new page with some $_GET parameters. After caching the browser navigate but the javascript rules are not applied after page refresh.

Also for smarty rules, eg. {if $smarty.get.test eq '1'}apply rules{/if}, so smarty read the cache but not the new rules get from url parameters.

So how can i solve this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way how to disable the Smarty cache for sections of your template files, the most straight forward one is to put the content you don't want to be cached into a `{nocache}`-tag, like this:

```
This is cached.
{nocache}
This is not cached!
{/nocache}
This is cached...again.
```

For further informations please look into the [Smarty manual.](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.cacheable.tpl#cacheability.sections)